# Using TextBlob library to understand sentiment and some sentences are coming back with 0 for polarity and sensitivity

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I have searched threads on here and found one other question that was the same but I did not understand the answer.

I am trying to understand sentiment of comments in a survey and for the comments fields, TextBlob will return a 0 for polarity and sentiment for about 30% of the comments in a column.  Why would this be?  I have tried removing punctuation and this does not seem to help.

An example sentence is something like "The long commute is making coming into work very challenging."  The word "challenging" to me does not seem like a neutral sentiment.  I also do not think this statement is total objective.

Could I make a change to the comments to make sure they run through the algorithm correctly?

Thank you!!

Comment: TextBlob's classifier's default performance will depend heavily on its training set. If that wasn't employee surveys (or representative of your task), it will suck. So label some of your data and update (retrain) the classifier: [Updating Classifiers with New Data](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html#updating-classifiers-with-new-data). Obviously partition your labeled training data separately from the test set, to avoid getting falsely optimistic peformance.

Comment: Also, show some specific data and code and output (polarity and sentiment scores) to make this a specific programming question and MCVE([mcve]).

Comment: I will try that - thank you!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add those clarifications? As stands this is neither specific programming question nor MCVE, so is not allowed on SO, and likely to be closed.

Comment: I will update it in a few hours. Thank you for the reminder. My son has covid so I have not been online much the last couple of days.

Comment: Oh sure. Good luck, will respond whenever you're able to update.